# Accessing Chrome only websites on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

I am trying to build an app that scrape data from a certain website that is restricted to access by Chrome only and that too Android/PC/Mac. It does not even work on Chrome iOS. When I use WebKit to connect to the site it says “Please use the latest version of Chrome to access this”. How can I bypass this restriction? Any help would by appreciated!

Comment: I would take a look at this [SO Set User Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219997/how-can-i-set-the-user-agent-header-of-a-uiwebview-in-swift) and see if setting the user agent helps.

Comment: That worked! Thanks